# Trying to ignore task on certain playbook

Tags: ansible

Right now I have two playbooks that I execute. One for a code_update and one for the entire site update. I'd like to have a "Quick Code Update", that doesn't run any of the NPM tasks.

Currently the task looks as such:

```
    ---
- name: Create app database
  mysql_db: name={{ app_db_name }} state=present

- name: Copy deploy key
  copy:
    src: templates/path.pem
    dest: "{{ ssh_key_path }}"
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"
    mode: 0600

- name: Create app dir
  file:
    path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"

- name: Create log dir
  file:
    path: "{{ log_dir }}"
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    mode: 0755
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"

- name: Pull sixnexus app
  git:
    repo: "{{ app_repo }}"
    dest: "{{ app_dir }}"
    version: master
    force: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
    ssh_opts: "-i {{ ssh_key_path }}"

- name: Create venv
  pip:
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"
    requirements: "{{ app_dir }}/requirements.txt"

- name: Copy local_settings.py
  template:
    src: templates/local_settings.py.j2
    dest: "{{ app_dir }}/local_settings.py"
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"
    mode: 0755

- name: Run migrations
  django_manage:
    command: migrate
    app_path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"

# Partially doing this to save on memory
- name: Stop Elasticsearch
  service: name=elasticsearch state=stopped

- name: Install react deps
  command: npm install chdir=/home/ubuntu/path/app/react_ui

- name: Package react app
  command: npm run package chdir=/home/ubuntu/path/app/react_ui

- name: Start Elasticsearch
  service: name=elasticsearch state=started

- name: Run collectstatic
  django_manage:
    command: collectstatic
    app_path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"
```

I'd like to edit the play to look like this:

```
---
- name: Create app database
  mysql_db: name={{ app_db_name }} state=present

- name: Copy deploy key
  copy:
    src: templates/sixnexus_deploy_key.pem
    dest: "{{ ssh_key_path }}"
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"
    mode: 0600

- name: Create app dir
  file:
    path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    state: directory
    mode: 0755
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"

- name: Create log dir
  file:
    path: "{{ log_dir }}"
    state: directory
    recurse: yes
    mode: 0755
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"

- name: Pull sixnexus app
  git:
    repo: "{{ app_repo }}"
    dest: "{{ app_dir }}"
    version: master
    force: yes
    accept_hostkey: yes
    ssh_opts: "-i {{ ssh_key_path }}"

- name: Create venv
  pip:
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"
    requirements: "{{ app_dir }}/requirements.txt"

- name: Copy local_settings.py
  template:
    src: templates/local_settings.py.j2
    dest: "{{ app_dir }}/local_settings.py"
    owner: "{{ app_user }}"
    mode: 0755

- name: Run migrations
  django_manage:
    command: migrate
    app_path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"

# Partially doing this to save on memory
- name: Stop Elasticsearch
  service: name=elasticsearch state=stopped
3

- name: Start Elasticsearch
  service: name=elasticsearch state=started

- name: Run collectstatic
  django_manage:
    command: collectstatic
    app_path: "{{ app_dir }}"
    virtualenv: "{{ app_env }}"
```

But, I can not figure how to incorporate a second file for my tasks.

Comment: I didn't get your question; the second version doesn't include `npm` tasks, do you want juste exclude them? In this case use the [tags](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_tags.html).

Comment: Re-reading the my question it is a little long winded. my applogies...I would like to have a second task that doesn't include the npm tasks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to tag related tasks:

```
- name: Install react deps
  command: npm install chdir=/home/ubuntu/path/app/react_ui
  tags:
    - npm

- name: Package react app
  command: npm run package chdir=/home/ubuntu/path/app/react_ui
  tags:
    - npm
```

And when you call your playbook, you have to specify the `--skip-tags` option:

```
$ ansible-playbook main.yml --skip-tags "npm"
```

Comment: just what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: would I also be able to do `$ ansible-playbook code_update.yml --skip-tags "npm"`

my code update play looks as follows 
`---
- name: Deploy app
  hosts: webservers
  become: yes
  roles:
    - sixnexus
    - nginx
    - gunicorn
`